# Media Projection in Service on Delphi

Tags: delphi, service, mediaprojection

I get user permision in main Activity:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var MPObj: JObject;
begin
FMessageSubscriptionID := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage( TMessageResultNotification, HandleActivityMessage );
MPObj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService( TJContext.JavaClass.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE );
MPManager := TJMediaProjectionManager.Wrap( ( MPObj as ILocalObject ).GetObjectID );
TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivityForResult( MPManager.createScreenCaptureIntent, 1234 );
end;

function TForm1.OnActivityResult( RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent ): Boolean;
var MediaProjectionData:JParcelable;
begin
       if ResultCode = -1 then
       begin
         ResIntent:=Data;
         TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService(????);
       end;
end;
```

I want to get MediaProjection in My Service:

```
  MPObj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService( TJContext.JavaClass.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE );
  MPManager := TJMediaProjectionManager.Wrap( ( MPObj as ILocalObject ).GetObjectID );
  mp := MpManager.getMediaProjection( -1, ResIntent );
```

How can I pass an object ResIntent or Data to my service?

Intent.PutExtra cannot pass data of type JIntent